# Unable to submit data to action method of .net core from angular 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, angular5

I am trying to post data from angular 5 component to action method of .net core. I am able to hit the action method but values are null. As per below example Usr.FirstName is null in Sush action method.

Model-

```
namespace VModels
{
    public class UserVM
    {
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Action method of .net core-

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Sush(UserVM Usr)        
{
    UserVM objOutput = new UserVM();
    CommonGetPostMethod<UserVM, UserVM> objCommonMthd = new CommonGetPostMethod<UserVM, UserVM>();
    UserVM objvm = new UserVM();
    objvm.FirstName = "Susheel " + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    objCommonMthd.SaveData(Usr, "https://localhost:44303/api/UserAPI", ref objOutput);            
    return View(Usr);
}
```

Post method in angular 5-

```
SaveUser(userofrm: NgForm) {    
    var model = userofrm.value;
    var values = JSON.stringify(model);       
    this.hpclient.post<UserVM>("https://localhost:44321/User/Users/Sush", values).subscribe(success => { }, fail => { });    
}
```

Comment: It would be of help if you provide a bit more details, like what's the value inside userofrm? Are you sure it does contains any data and when doing `var model = userofrm.value; var values = JSON.stringify(model);` is actually saving anything? I'd suggest you to log `userofrm` into the console to see if it contains any value or not.

Comment: @CarlosParra yes its writing proper value in console log - {"FirstName": "Test"}

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code that you provided, I did a test with the following simple example, which work well on my side, you can refer to it.

```
// make request with testing data

var model = {'FirstName':'Test'};
var values = JSON.stringify(model); 
console.log(values);      
this.hpclient.post<UserVM>("https://localhost:44305/api/data/Sush", values, httpOptions).subscribe(success => { console.log(success);}, fail => { });
```

*Define and configure headers for request(s)*

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders  } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};
```

*API controller action*

```
[HttpPost("Sush")]
public IActionResult Sush(UserVM Usr)
{
    Usr.UserId = 100;
    return Ok(Usr);
}
```

*Test Result*

[image]

To troubleshoot the issue, you can try to make request with same data from postman etc tool and check if you can get expected data within action method. Or make request with testing data (as I did) rather than value inside `userofrm`, then check if it can work for you.

Comment: It looks like you have created API Controller but I want call action method of controller not api controller

Comment: The point is you need to add the httpOptions object in your JavaScript.